# __METHOD__ and __FUNCTION__

Tags: php, function, class, methods, constants

I know the difference between these two, and I've checked the manual.

I am still confused about some points. I can use `__FUNCTION__` in a method; it represents the method name. This is clear.

Why can I use `__METHOD__` in a function?
This also just represents the function name.

```php
class dog {
    private $name = 'dog';
    
    public static function name() {
        echo __METHOD__;
        echo "\n";
        echo __FUNCTION__;
        echo "\n";
    }
    
}

function test() {
    echo __FUNCTION__;
    echo "\n";
    echo __METHOD__;
}
    
dog::name();
test();
```

This code outputs:

> dog::name
> name
> test
> test

Comment: both are same outside the class. You can use any of them but personally I use `__FUNCTION__`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

"Method" is basically just the name for a function within a class (or class function). Therefore `__METHOD__` consists of the class name and the function name called (`dog::name`), while `__FUNCTION__` only gives you the name of the function without any reference to the class it might be in.

When `__METHOD__` is called outside of a class it's the same as `__FUNCTION__` because there is no class part to be used as a prefix. You can use `__METHOD__` outside of a class because it's a magic constant and they're always available (at worst case they will return empty string).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: In your answer if misused not throw exceptios, I quickly read the manual again, and not found it. If I miss something.

Comment: The misuse of constants throws exceptions if you want to use constants that were defined as non-public inside of a class from outside. Magic Constants change depending on where they are used, but they are globally accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify your doubt..

- First I will explain about CLASS & OBJECT(what is the difference..)
- Then I will clarify about FUNCTION & METHOD(what is the difference..)

talking about Class :: It is a your logical implementation..

object :: It is a instance of your class (instance ~ COPY ~ clone ~ ...)

when you are using --NEW-- operator --->  you are creating an OBJECT (nothing but the COPY) OF YOUR CLASS.

CLASS =============> ~NEW~ =======> OBJECT (New Copy of your class..) similarly

FUNCTION ==========> ~NEW~ =======> METHOD (Belongs to Object not Class)

Class is the program you are writing while object is the copy of your class that is executing..

class resides in ROM(permanent) where as object resides in RAM(temporary memory area..)

& when you are declaring an function as static it belongs only to class not to object & you can call the same(static function)
by using ClassName::staticFunctionName()

That is why there is no existence of STATIC_METHOD Rather STATIC_FUNCTION !!!

code example::

```
<?php

class Dog extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index($params = '') {
  }

  private $name = 'dog';

  public static function name() {
    echo 'Inside static function & inside class' . '<br>';
    echo __METHOD__ . '<br>';
    echo __FUNCTION__ . '<br>';
  }

  public function test2() {
    echo 'Inside NON STATIC function & inside class' . '<br>';
    echo __FUNCTION__ . '<br>';
    echo __METHOD__ . '<br>';
  }
}

function test() {
  echo 'Inside NON STATIC function & OUTSIDE class' . '<br>';
  echo __FUNCTION__ . '<br>';
  echo __METHOD__ . '<br>';
}

Dog::name();
test();
$somevar = new Dog;
$somevar->test2();
```

OUTPUT::

```
Inside static function & inside class
Dog::name               //Class::function
name
    
Inside NON STATIC function & OUTSIDE class
test
test
    
Inside NON STATIC function & inside class
test2
Dog::test2            //Object::method
```

IN Your case
as you are using **METHOD** IN static context it showing the class name
if the it would be a non static(Simple Function) it would show only function name only..

Answer (score 1):

in every programming language.. Method always corresponds to Object.
Method <==> Object
while Function always corresponds to both class & Object(Static Function).

and finally there is no existence of Static Method

&

In this case..

**METHOD**        => includes class name
**FUNCTION**      => Only refers to function name

if any clarification contact me..

Comment: As you can see in my code I the `__METHOD__` in a function which is not in a class, it not show the class name.

Comment: yes, your function test() resides outside of the class & if it would have inside  the class [NON STATIC ] It would have return the class name and method(Not to confuse with function) Name..